# How to make a HA load balanced setup on base of Rancher with Cattle environment?

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, rancher

So I have 3 hosts (VPS) configured in Rancher (Cattle) and I want them to be available on 1 entry point with no dependancy on failover of any of the hosts. In Rancher environment I created a Load Balancer to route requests between services/hosts (so I have 3 IP's), but I don't know how to make a single HA entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically users have a physical or cloud based load balancer infront of the Rancher servers. If you dont have the ability to do that, you could do RR-DNS, but that has some serious drawbacks due to TTLs.

Some users can move a floating IP Address between the nodes using something like keepalived.